# Shell splitting in subshell

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

I have unclear information about word splitting in Shell and subshells.

Example:

```
IFS=""
file_name="file with space"
file_name=$(real_path $file_name)
```

Will `$file_name` get split in subshell? Or do I have to double-quote it like so:

```
file_name=$(real_path "$file_name")
```

After some testing I found out that:

- if I set `IFS=" "`, then `$file_name` gets split by spaces
- if `IFS=""` then whole `$file_name` is passed as first parameter.

ksh, dash, and bash all show this behavior so far.

Comment: forget the IFS stuff:   a. echo "$*" concatenates all arguments as one argument,  while   b. echo "$@" wraps quotes around each blank-separated argument.    the security wizards suggest using "${file_name}" to guarantee it's a single argument, regardless of blanks.  IFS, while useful, shouldn't enter defense-against-blanks-in-file-name discussions.

Answer (score 2):

It will not word split since you set IFS to the empty string before forking the subshell, but you will still have to quote it to prevent pathname expansion.